# Algorithm for sorting people into rooms based on age and nationality

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I’m working on program for the English Language school I work for. I’m not being paid, its just a kind of a hobby to improve / automate my work flow.

It’s a residential school and one aspects I’m looking at automating is the way we allocate room to students, and although I don’t want a full blown solution I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction… Suggestions of the way you might approach this or by suggesting algorithms to look at etc.

Basically at the school we have a whole bunch of different rooms ranging from singles to dormitories for 8 people.  We get lots of different nationalities from all over the world, and we always try to maker sure each room has a mix of nationalities. Where there is more than one nationality we try to balance them. Age is also important, we always put students of a similar age together, while still trying to mix nationalities, and its unusual for us to have students sharing with more than two years between them.

I suppose more generically speaking, I am in interested in how to sort a given set of students based on two parameters to an optimal result with a few rules attached.

I hope I’ve explain clearly what I am trying to achieve… in a way it sounds really simple, but I’ve trying to think how to do it in a simple way, i.e. by sorting by nationality and then by age but it just doesn’t cut it and I know there must be a better way of approaching this. When I do it “by hand” on an excel sheet it does feel quite intuitive.

Thank you to anyone who offers help / advice.

Comment: nice wrap up but it sounds like homework. And this is not really a programming question -1

Comment: I'm not sure how to convince you that its not homework, but for what its worth, I can assure you its not. I'm in full time employment and not studying, hence the "wrap up". Why does it matter anyway? Its about algorithm design, and algorithms are a large part of what programming is all about.

Comment: You need a lot more rules for finding appropriate configurations. Do you want small rooms filled first? Or large ones? Do you allow partially filled rooms? Do you have penalties for that? Is gender important? etc etc

Comment: Indeed there are more variables to the problem, but I wanted to cut it down to the main part that I was having problems with. Gender for instance is important, but easily handled because we don't allow mixing genders. Partially filled rooms allowed? Yes, but only if there aren't enough students to fill them, i.e. if we have 4 rooms of 4, and 13 students then some rooms could have 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question but it's not easy to answer. Somehow it's connected with subdivsion and bin packing or the cutting-stock problem. You may want to look for a topological sort too. You can look for Drools a business logic platform that let you define such rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into those. I'll look up Drool just out of interest, but for what its worth I'm interested in rolling my own, specifically in Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you might find this interesting: [Stable Room-mates Problem (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem). Unfortunately it does not answer your question.

Try a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

There are three main criteria for using a genetic algorithm:

- ability to represent a solution as a mutable array. We can have an array of integers such that a[i] is the room for the ith student.
- mutation of the state should produce predictable results. In our case this is true. Mutating the array will predictably shuffle students between the rooms.
- easy to write a fast fitness function. Shouldn't be too hard to write a O(n) fitness function.

This is an interesting problem. I'll try writing some code with this approach and we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

How about, you think of a room as something that repels students of a nationality it already has, and attracts students of a close age to what it already has. The closer the age to the average age, the more it attracts it, and the more guys of X nationality are in the room, the more if repels guys of X nationality.

Then you would, for every new student to be added, iterate through each room and see which is the one that attracts it more. I guess if the room is empty you can set all forces to 0. Also, you would have a couple of constants that multiply each of both "forces" so you can calibrate it depending on how important is to have the same age against how important is to have different nationalities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd analyze each student and create a 'personality' vector based on his/her age & nationality. Then I'd sort the vectors, and maybe scramble the results a bit after sorting to encourage diversity.

Answer (score 0):

The general theme of "assign x to y with respect to constraints while optimizing some quantity" falls within operations research or more specifically http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization. The usual approach is to formally specify the problem and use a generic optimization solver such as one of those listed in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optimization_software.

Give it a try, the formal specification languages for using the existing solvers are rather easy to learn and you might get an optimal solution without having to debug a complicated algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

### Formulation as a General Optimization Problem

It will be useful to formalize constraints and parameters. Let us assume that for 1 <= i <= 8, we have n_i rooms available of size i. Now let us impose the hard constraint that in a particular room S, every two students a, b \in S, we have that:

```
|Grade(a) - Grade(b)| <= 2 (1)
```

Now we are interested in optimizing the "diversity" function which intuitively represents the idea that we want rooms to be as mixed as possible. So we can represent this goal as:

```
max over all arrangements {{ Sum over all rooms S of DiversityScore(S) }}
    where we have DiversityScore(S) = # of Different Nationalities in the Room
```

### Formulation as a Graph Problem

This is the most general setting, but clearly max over all arrangements is not computationally feasible. Now let us pose this as a sort of graph problem with the hard grade constraints. Denote all students as a vertex in a Graph G. Connect two vertices if students satisfy constraint (1). Now a clique in this graph represents a group of students that can all be placed in the same room. Now proceed in a greedy manner. Choose the largest clique of size 4 which has the largest Diversity Score. Then place them in a room and continue until all rooms are filled. This clique search method can also incorporate gender constraints which is useful, however not that Clique finding is NP Hard Problem.

Now before trying to come up with something that may be faster, let us think about how to weaken the hard constraint (1). We can massage our graph formulation by including edge weights into the picture. So if the hard constraint is satisfied denote the edge weight from i to j as 1. If two students i and j deviate by age more than 2 denote the edge weight as 1 / (Age Difference)^2 or something. Then the score of a clique should be a product of the cliques edge weights with some diversity score. However it becomes clear that now the problem is on a complete graph, which is just the general optimization we hoped to avoid, so we need to impose some hard restrictions to reduce the connectivity of our graph.

### A Basic Sorting Approximation Algorithm

Sort all students by their age, so we have a sorted array where all students in a[i] have the same age, and all students in a[i] are older than all students in a[j] for all j < i.
Now consider each pair i, j, of which there are O(n^2), where we also have that |Age[i] - Age[j]| <= 2. Find the largest group of students with different nationalities and place them in a room together. We successively iterate over O(n^2) index pairs which satisfy the hard constraint and take any students with nationality difference (which we can find by preprocessing and hashing on the index pairs). Doing this carefully (like looking at indices i j which are spread apart before close together) improves running time further. It feels like it should be polytime, but I think there are certain subtleties to address first before saying so.